# Not able to _.debounce and change the state in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash's debounce method to to toggle a boolean located in the state 500ms after the scroll occured.

I've look for responses on SO but none of these helped me to fix this. This seems fairly simple so there's probably something that I didn't get.

The state is:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       isScrolling: false
    }
 }
```

The componentDidMount part is:

```
   componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _.debounce(() => {
      this.setState({
        isScrolling: false
      })
    }, 500))
 }
```

The scroll function is:

```
    handleScroll = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        isScrolling: true
      })
    };
```

In my rect chrome dev. tools, I see that `isScrolling` is toggling to true when I start scrolling but the `debounce` method does not toggle it `back` to false again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is correct, I copied it into a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/gOYobGQ?editors=0010). It must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - My code was correct but this bit of css code was preventing the correct behavior to happen:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
```